# Ajax.BeginForm not doing an asynchronous post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I am having problem with Ajax.BeginForm for long now is search over the internet and SO but most of solutions of including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min` or editing `web.config` to allow `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` which in my case both are done but still my ajax form is doing a full post back and can’t understand why.

In `View`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "User", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "loginResult" }, new { @id = "loginForm", @name = "loginForm" }))
    {
        <span id="loginResultx">@(TempData["loginResult"] != null ? TempData["loginResult"].ToString() : "")</span>
        <span id="loginResult"></span>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("User Id")
            @Html.TextBox("id")</span>
        <span>@Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.Password("pwd")
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </span>
    }
```

in `Controller`

```
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection loginForm)
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var id= loginForm["id"];
            var pwd = loginForm["pwd"];
            bool status = false;
            User obj = new User();
            status = obj.Login(id, pwd);
            if (status)
            {
                Session["id "] = id;
                return RedirectToRoute("Profile");

            }

            TempData["loginResult"] = "Login Failed";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

In  `BundleConfig`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scr").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the bundle loads the script correctly? do you have any javacript error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not this line that is the problem?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scr").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min"));
```

You are missing a .js from the ajax file include. Do you see it?

Either way, I would use Chrome inspector/Fiddler to analyse any JS errors or missing includes.